Creating a dynamically loadable shared archive on AIX with CMake
I'm attempting to create a dynamically loadable shared archive on AIX using CMake. I'm able to create a library successfully, however it fails to load with dlopen.
func.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    void func(void) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Hello, World!\n"); 
    }
}

direct.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    void func(void);
}

int main(void) {
    func();
    return 0;
}

dynamic.cpp
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void* lib = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!lib) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    typedef void (*func_t)(void);
    func_t func = (func_t)dlsym(lib, "func");
    if (!func) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(lib);
        return 1;
    }
    func();
    dlclose(lib);

    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)

project(example)

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "AIX" AND CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL "3.26" AND CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.27")
    string(REPLACE "objects.exp" "exports.exp" CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY}")
endif()

add_library(example SHARED func.cpp)

add_executable(dynamic dynamic.cpp)

target_link_libraries(dynamic PRIVATE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

add_executable(direct direct.cpp)

target_link_libraries(direct PRIVATE example)

This code works successfully on Linux, and I'm able to execute both ./direct and ./dynamic ./libexample.so successfully (they print "Hello, World!").
The build is successful on AIX, and ./direct works successfully, however when I execute ./dynamic ./libexample.a, it fails with the following error:
ERROR:  0509-022 Cannot load module ./libexample.a.
        0509-026 System error: Cannot run a file that does not have a valid format.

For reference, I'm working on AIX 7.3 with the xlC_r 16.1.0 compiler, and with CMake 3.26.4.
EDIT:
For some additional context, I'm using the default generator. CMake produces the following output when configuring the build:
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is XL 16.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is XL 16.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/IBM/xlC/16.1.0/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/IBM/xlC/16.1.0/bin/xlC - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (1.2s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: /experiment/build_aix


Well, CMake is platform independent, which means it doesn't really support exotic platforms like Aix. Right now you should create standalone shared object libexample.so not one that is packed into an ar-archive.

The fact that your add_library() call produces a static archive instead of a dynamic library as you have instructed it with the SHARED flag suggests that, as @LorinczyZsigmond pointed out, CMake does not know how to deal with the compiler you pointed out. What's the output of CMake when it configures? What generator are you using? You could look at what rules CMake has generated to see whether it has gotten anywhere close to correct

@LorinczyZsigmond CMake claims support for AIX (https://github.com/Kitware/CMake)

@Pesho_T It didn't produce a static archive, this is an AIX shared archive. ./direct will load ./libexample.a at runtime.

@DRH apologies, I am not familiar with AIX. Have you come across the AIX_SHARED_LIBRARY_ARCHIVE target property? Looks like it controls whether the SO goes in an archive or not, if this is an acceptable solution. A quick web search on AIX shared lib archives also brought this up, in case it helps?
